# How do I use searchoption for toolbar search in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I have problem to use searchoption when my data column in array PHP my
.js

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            dataType: "json",
            data:{id_student:id_student,id_buku :id_buku},
            success:function(msg){
                    var colnames = msg[0];
                    var colmodels = msg[1];
                    
                    grid_selector.jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        height: 394,
                        ignoreCase: true,
                        viewsortcols : [true,'vertical',true],
                        colNames: colnames,
                        colModel: colmodels,
...
});
                jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('filterToolbar');
```

my .php

```
$key = array_keys($dt[0]);
        
        $row = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++){
            $row[$i]['date'] = $key[$i];
            $row[$i]['index'] = $key[$i];
            
            if($row[$i]['date']=='user_date'){
                $row[$i]['width'] = 100;
                $row[$i]['searchoption'] = date;
            }
            else {
                $row[$i]['width'] = 70; 
            }
        }
```

How do I customize column search with date? I'm so sorry if my English is bad

Comment: Please share more details - what's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @NicoHaase so sorry for not add more detail , i have problem when use searchoption in php , i have example when in js in here [link] http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/searching/toolbar_options/index.html , ihave no idea how use searchoption in php

Comment: im so sorry my english bad

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it

Comment: Hello, I highly recommend you to read the [documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/)